# Stored Procedure - Invalid cursor state

Tags: python

I am trying to run a stored procedure and im getting the error below. I tried doing AutoCommit = True but still no luck.

error:

```
pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('24000', '[24000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid cursor state')
```

code

```
 def sqlConnection():
conn = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};''Server=test;''Database=test;'
                        'Trusted_Connection=yes;autocommit=True')

cursor = conn.cursor()


return conn, cursor

def payments(cursor, conn):
    cd = datetime.today()
    formatted_date = datetime.strftime(cd, "%m/%d/%Y")

     payments_q = """\
        EXEC pRptMonTrTypeSumm @jobkey=?, @cdate=?
        """
      params = (1, '08/30/2020')
      fpl_payments_results = cursor.execute(payments_q, params)

       for row in payments_results.fetchall():
       payments3 = row[4]
       print(payments3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `SET NOCOUNT ON;` before the stored procedure.

Comment: how do you do that? in the actual part EXEC pRptMonTrTypeSumm @jobkey=?, @cdate=?

Comment: SET NOCOUNT ON;
          EXEC pRptMonTrTypeSumm @jobkey=?, @cdate=?